# Is there any way to print strings in C as the follows: puts("this is a string" + variable);?

Tags: c, string, variables, concatenation, puts

Is there any ways to to program this?

```
puts("this is a string" + variable);
```

Maybe different syntax but printing the variable and the string using the puts() in the same line.

Comment: You *do* know about [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)? It's one of the very first functions just about any beginner book or tutorial will show you.

Comment: I am curious, where are you learning C coding from?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called `printf`.  For example:

```
printf("this is a string %s\n", variable);
```

Assuming `variable` is a string (a `char *`), this will substitute `%s` with the string, then end it in a newline.

If `variable` is a number, there are number formats you can use (e.g. `%d` for an `int`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `printf` function for Print a formatted string to the
>   console.
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main(void) {
>   char variable[] = "with a variable.";
>   printf("this is a string %s", variable);
>   return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> if you want to learn more about printf function go [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html)

Comment: I know about printf() but I was hoping there was a short cut like in cpp or java. Anyways, thank you guys.